# Kubctl accessing a Kubernetes Cluster created with Private IP

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm

I created a Kubernetes Cluster using kubadm and the private IP of the server so all the nodes could reach it withing the cloudprovider network. I am using 4 nodes in DigitalOcean.

```
kubctl-s-2vcpu-4gb-nyc3-01-master:~# kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://10.132.113.68:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

The command I used to initialize the cluster is:

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=10.132.113.68 --kubernetes-version stable-1.8
```

I am trying to connect to this cluster using kubectl from my local computer. The admin.conf file has the private IP:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS********S0tLQo=
    server: https://10.132.113.68:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
```

I have tried setting up the proxy in the master `kubectl proxy` and making an SSH tunnel to the server:

```
ssh -L 8001:127.0.0.1:8001 -N -i test.pem root@104.236.XX.209
```

I can login into the Kubernetes Dashboard from my computer, but can't execute `kubectl` commands:

```
$kubectl -s localhost:8001 get nodes
Unable to connect to the server: read tcp 127.0.0.1:62394->127.0.0.1:8001: read: connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 1):

Where `ssh -L ...`  ends, `sshuttle` starts :): it creates local tcp "catch-all" DNATing via the ssh dest node, ie will forward **every** tcp connection in the specified *CIDR*.

Try it out:

- In one terminal (to ease later ^C):

  `sshuttle -e 'ssh -vi test.pem' -r root@104.236.XX.209 10.132.113.68/32`
- From other terminal, just do the `kubectl ...` as you would do if locally run from your initial `kubeadm` node.
- Profit :)

--jjo

Comment: Do you have ~./kube/config file on the local machine and is this file readable by the user?

Comment: @d0bry: yep - that `sshuttle` trick only covers the networking side, so indeed you'll need to have a local kubernetes ctx, it could also be copied/saved to other location and be used with `export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config-remote-blah` if you don't want to "merge" the remote context with your existing ones

Comment: I tried different approaches using shuttle but none of them seem to work as expected. I am not even sure if this is something you do with Kubernetes.